# Lebesgue integrability if xf(x) is integrable in R+

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

If xf(x) is Lebesgue integrable in R+, how do I show that:
f(x)exp(-tx) is integrable for every t and x in R+? 
[image]

For the exercise 9.1
I've been trying to use the conditions of mesurability of f(x)exp(-tx) which is okay.
Showing that f(x)exp(-tx) is continue in relation to t
and what it's needed is just to show integrability of f(x)exp(-tx) to be sure that F(x) is defined.

Comment: You don't, because it's false.

Comment: I'm not sure, can you show it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your own thoughts and efforts, and I'd be happy to. What is the source of the problem? Why do you think it's true? What techniques do you know?

Comment: Okay, I'll do it, thanks.
I'm in this problem it's been almost 2h. The source is my french textbook, can I post a photo?

Comment: The fact that **both** $f$ and $xf$ are integrable is key here. Use integrability of $f$ to get well-definition. The only place that $xf$ comes in is when you prove differentiability.

Comment: Well f(x) is not necessarily integrable, if it were that would be simple =). Thank you very much anyway

Comment: Sorry, I misread it, im so mad at myself right now =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your exercise it's given that $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\Bbb R_+)$ hence we have $$\int_{\Bbb R_+} |f(x)| dx < \infty$$

Additionally for each $$t,x \in \Bbb R_+$$ we have $$e^{-tx} \le 1$$ and we get:

$$\int_{\Bbb R_+} |f(x)e^{-tx}| dx\quad \le \quad  \int_{\Bbb R_+} |f(x)| dx \quad < \quad  \infty$$ what gives the wanted result.

Comment: the integral of |xf(x)| <+infinity actually

Comment: No… check your exercise where it's given "soit $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Bbb R_+)$". You have the integrability of $xf(x)$ in addition. But it's not necessary to conclude the integrability of $f(x)e^{-tx}$.

Comment: actually "soit (xf(x))∈L1(R+)". I think you mess up the notations
x -> g(x) ∈ L1(R+) with g(x)=xf(x) (that's actually what it meant)

Comment: SOrryyy !! I didn't see that, my mistake, i've been trying to do that for years aaaaahh im so mad at myself right nowww